# Flutter: Disable inkwell color

Tags: flutter, dart

**PROBLEM:**
How we can disable color for inkwell so that if we click on it nothing shows up but click should work as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:
Just pass transparent color in 2 properties of Inkwell

1. highlightColor
2. splashColor

Now if you click there will be no color but onTap will work.

```
           InkWell(
                    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Hello D");
                    },
                    child: Container(
                    ),
```

Comment: Just use an ordinary button instead

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler you can use a GestureDetector class

```
...
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => doSomething(),
    child: Text("click here"),
)
...
```